# ProcessBuilder Does Not Output Anything

Tags: java, processbuilder

I run a shell command with Process Builder:

```
try {
    ProcessBuilder lmBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("/home/istanbul/srilm/bin/i686-m64/ngram-count", "-text", modelPath, "-order", "3", "-lm", modelOutputPath);
    lmBuilder.redirectErrorStream();
    final Process lmProcess = lmBuilder.start();
    int result = lmProcess.waitFor(); //result becomes 0
    InputStream is = lmProcess.getInputStream();
    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);

    String line;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
    }

} catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

When I check the output of the command I see that it works properly. When I run it via shell I see that output:

```
warning: discount coeff 1 is out of range: 0
warning: discount coeff 7 is out of range: 1.06876
warning: discount coeff 7 is out of range: 2.09945
```

However when I run it **via process builder I cannot see any output**.

Any ideas?

Comment: Isn't your call to `waitFor()` blocking? Shouldn't the Streams be read in their own threads, threads which get started before calling `waitFor()`?

Comment: Try using [`ProcessBuilder#inheritIO`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#inheritIO()) and see if that helps

Comment: @MadProgrammer you are right, inheritIO works at my case. However redirectErrorStream(true) works too.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels You are right. After fixing redirectErrorStream() as redirectErrorStream(true) now it works. However when I use waitFor() application is blocked. How can I sure that all output is emitted by Buffered Reader?

Comment: Typically, it read the streams through another thread and block the current thread with waitFor

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
lmBuilder.redirectErrorStream();
```

This is incorrect.

This method only *tells* whether you redirect stderr to stdout; it does not instruct that stderr should be redirected to it.

What you should use is:

```
lmBuilder.redirectErrorStream(true);
```

Comment: You are right, when I don't use redirectErrorStream or redirectErrorStream() it doesn't output anything. However I have another problem, when I don't use waitFor() it outputs properly bu when I use waitFor() application is blocked. How can I sure that all output is emitted by Buffered Reader?